# Does Java URLConnection send Metadata?

Tags: java, html, url, metadata, privacy

when you open a connection via URLConnection to read the content of a Webpage,

```
try {
     URL url = new URL("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46939965/does-java-urlconnection-send-metadata");
     URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
     HttpURLConnection connection;
     connection = (HttpURLConnection) urlConnection;

     BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
     String current;

     while((current = in.readLine()) != null) {
        urlString += current;
     }
  }catch(IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

what will Java leave for Information?
Will statistical data like the Webbrowser saved? Will that be the "Java"?

Thx for help,
~Corn

Answer (score 0):

HTTP "metadata" is normally sent in the [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers).  The one that would indicate the web browser is typically called "USER_AGENT." I do not believe Java will populate these headers for you implicitly.